# machine goes to DHCP after reboot

Tags: reboot, dhcp, ip

Our server if rebooted goes to DHCP even if we have provided static IP to the server. What all changes needs to be done so that even machine reboots it will boot with static IP. Pl. help.

Comment: How did you provide a static IP to the server? Can you elaborate and provide further details pleasE?

Answer (score 1):

Edit `/etc/network/interfaces` file (requires root / sudo access) and provide details for the IP addresses required.

An example is:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.10.10.15
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 10.10.10.10.0
    broadcast 10.10.10.255
    gateway 10.10.10.1
```

Restart networking with `/etc/init.d/networking restart`

Remember also to set up DNS servers - if you use `resolvconf` service (check by `service resolvconf status`), then you may add the desired DNS server entry to `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` file:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver      10.10.10.1
nameserver      8.8.8.8
```

and restart `resolvconf` by issuing `service resolvconf restart`.